# Is the process of creating an Associated Token Account idempotent?

Tags: spl-token-program, associated-token-account

I was unable to determine from the documentation if the process of creating Associated Token Accounts is idempotent:

- https://spl.solana.com/associated-token-account#creating-an-associated-token-account

Is the best practice when transferring tokens to always assume that the ADA does not exist and create the ATA right before transferring the tokens? Or will that result in some kind of error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can call:

https://solana-labs.github.io/solana-program-library/token/js/modules.html#getOrCreateAssociatedTokenAccount before to ensure it exist.

Or if you want to be more efficient, check if it exists and if not, prepend the instructions to create it before you transfer instructions.

That's usually what I do, I got a `getOrCreateAtaInstruction` that returns `null` or the `TransactionInstruction`.

Comment: What about race conditions? What if two parties are trying to send the same token at the same time to a wallet that never had the token before? If both ask the system if it exists at the same time and both see that it does not exist, one of them creates it ok and the other one attempts to create it after it already exists from the first one. It's a rare problem that could be handled special I guess. :D

Comment: Can use init_if_needed in Anchor , but feels like an overkill for this use case

Comment: I agree, it is overkill. :)